# Parsing a log file

Tags: php, mysql, json, logging, text-parsing

I have a log file "file.log". I tried to parse the file in php to get the key value pair.

```
Notification: {
"state" : "PROGRESSING",
"version" : "2012-09-25",
"jobId" : "xxxxxxxxx",
"pipelineId" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"input" : {
   "key" : "upload2/xxxxx",
   "frameRate" : "auto",
   "resolution" : "auto",
   "aspectRatio" : "auto",
   "interlaced" : "auto",
   "container" : "auto"
 },
"outputKeyPrefix" : "output2/test4/",
"outputs" : [ {
   "id" : "1",
   "presetId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "key" : "xxxxxxxx",
   "rotate" : "auto",
   "status" : "Progressing"
    } ]
  }
```

I have changed the values . I tried to parse it by this php code.

```
<?php
$myFile = "file.log";
$lines = file($myFile);
foreach ($lines as $no => $ln) {
$out = explode(":", $ln);
echo($out[1]);
echo(trim($out[1]));
?>
```

I'm getting my output as

> { { "PROGRESSING", "PROGRESSING", "2012-09-25", "2012-09-25", "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

It keeps going on.. Not in the right format. I wanted it as key value pair. How to do that? Please guys need help! I also need to retrieve them and store it in database using mysql.

Comment: It looks like a json file. Use a json parser

Comment: try with `json_decode()` once. I think its in json format.

Comment: no. its a log file of a transcoding job

Comment: when i try with json decode I'm getting this error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
$logFile = file_get_contents('logfile.log');

// first we replace all instances of the string "Notification: " with a comma to separate the json objects
$cleanLog = str_replace("Notification: ",",",$logFile);

// next we replace the first comma
$cleanLog = '[' . ltrim($cleanLog,",") . ']';

// construct the list of object
$objects = json_decode($cleanLog);

// use this main loop to iterate over all Notification rows
foreach ($objects as $object){
    // write a mysql insert statement here, 
    // you can address each object and inner members as follows:

    print $object->state . PHP_EOL;
    print $object->outputKeyPrefix . PHP_EOL;
    print $object->outputs[0]->id . PHP_EOL;
    print $object->input->key . PHP_EOL;
}
```

using this log file sample as reference:

`logfile.log`

```
Notification: {
"state" : "PROGRESSING",
"version" : "2012-09-25",
"jobId" : "xxxxxxxxx",
"pipelineId" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"input" : {
   "key" : "upload2/xxxxx",
   "frameRate" : "auto",
   "resolution" : "auto",
   "aspectRatio" : "auto",
   "interlaced" : "auto",
   "container" : "auto"
 },
"outputKeyPrefix" : "output2/test4/",
"outputs" : [ {
   "id" : "1",
   "presetId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "key" : "xxxxxxxx",
   "rotate" : "auto",
   "status" : "Progressing"
    } ]
  }
Notification: {
"state" : "PROGRESSING",
"version" : "2012-09-25",
"jobId" : "xxxxxxxxx",
"pipelineId" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"input" : {
   "key" : "upload2/xxxxx",
   "frameRate" : "auto",
   "resolution" : "auto",
   "aspectRatio" : "auto",
   "interlaced" : "auto",
   "container" : "auto"
 },
"outputKeyPrefix" : "output2/test4/",
"outputs" : [ {
   "id" : "1",
   "presetId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "key" : "xxxxxxxx",
   "rotate" : "auto",
   "status" : "Progressing"
    } ]
  }
Notification: {
"state" : "PROGRESSING",
"version" : "2012-09-25",
"jobId" : "xxxxxxxxx",
"pipelineId" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"input" : {
   "key" : "upload2/xxxxx",
   "frameRate" : "auto",
   "resolution" : "auto",
   "aspectRatio" : "auto",
   "interlaced" : "auto",
   "container" : "auto"
 },
"outputKeyPrefix" : "output2/test4/",
"outputs" : [ {
   "id" : "1",
   "presetId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "key" : "xxxxxxxx",
   "rotate" : "auto",
   "status" : "Progressing"
    } ]
  }
```

---

The string after the "Notification: " bit is valid `json`. You can parse it as follows:

```
<?php

$string = '{
"state" : "PROGRESSING",
"version" : "2012-09-25",
"jobId" : "xxxxxxxxx",
"pipelineId" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"input" : {
   "key" : "upload2/xxxxx",
   "frameRate" : "auto",
   "resolution" : "auto",
   "aspectRatio" : "auto",
   "interlaced" : "auto",
   "container" : "auto"
 },
"outputKeyPrefix" : "output2/test4/",
"outputs" : [ {
   "id" : "1",
   "presetId" : "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "key" : "xxxxxxxx",
   "rotate" : "auto",
   "status" : "Progressing"
    } ]
  }';

// construct object  
$object = json_decode($string);

// call each property of the object or inner object

print $object->state . PHP_EOL;
// PROGRESSING

print $object->outputKeyPrefix . PHP_EOL;  
// output2/test4/

print $object->outputs[0]->id . PHP_EOL;
// 1

// or, for multiple outputs

foreach ($object->outputs as $output)
    print $output->rotate . PHP_EOL;
// auto
```

Comment: The code is not working if I include the file using file_get_contents ($filename)

Comment: I will update the answer with code to properly parse the logfile

Comment: $string does not contain "Notification". String cannot be edited as its coming from a file which does not needs to be editied.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to strip out the "Notification: " part and ultimately end up with a valid `json` string. I only assumed on how a multi-entry log sample looks like, but the code should be good enough for reference.

Comment: Thanks man.. It worked.. :-) . Now how do i save each entry of the notification as a seperate row in mysql. Should I use insert command in mysql inside foreach loop??

Comment: I edited the main `foreach` block to show where the `insert` should go. It's pretty easy to address each object and its members, the `print` and `PHP_EOL` are just for illustration :)

Comment: i tried inserting the values inside ms sql server by following statement but it keeps showing error. This is my code '$sql ="insert into transcoder(st) VALUES ('".$object->state."')";
 $result=sqlsrv_query($sql,$conn);
 if($result)
 {
  echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Failure";
 }' @ Alex Andrei

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92111/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-reaching-out).

Answer (score 0):

Not a matter , if your json string is not in json file .. you may parse it as-

```
<?php
$myFile = "file.log";
$json = file_get_contents($myFile);
$json= explode(":",$json,2);
$json=$json[1];
$obj=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($obj);

?>
```

Comment: still not showing output. Thank You though Got the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myFile = "file.log";
$str = file_get_contents($myFile);
$json = trim(strstr($str, ':'), ': ');
print_r(json_decode($json));// for Object
print_r(json_decode($json, true));// for Array
```

Actually "Notification" is preventing the string to be read as JSON. As valid json should start from curly braces or square brackets,
we remove "Notification" first and then trim the extra spaces or double colon from both sides of string. Thus only valid JSON remains.

Comment: I should not remove them. That is how I get my file. I shouldn't go in and edit each time.

Comment: You don't have to remove them, this code will automatically remove them. It tracks the first occurrence of double colon and then removes anything before it which is "Notification" in this case.

Comment: Not getting any output.. Got the answer though . thank you.